# Find longest path through an undirected edge-weighted tree

Tags: graph-theory, graph-traversal

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the longest path through an edge weighted tree.  The graph is acyclic and connected, but **not directed** and only **sparsely connected**, doesn't have a defined start point and can have many leaf nodes.  The longest path can only traverse an edge and pass through a vertex once.

A simplified representation as shown in this example where the edge weights are proportional to their length

[image]

would have the solution B-C-D-G-H-I.

I've had a look at the standard graph traversal algorithms, e.g. BFS, DFS, MST, etc; but none seem to be a good fit for my problem.

Before I go and implement a brute force algorithm I thought I would check here for any suggested solutions.

Comment: "would have the solution B-C-D-G-H-I." This is not THE solution.  A-C-D-G-H-I and other paths are just as long

Comment: @ravenspoint The OP is using the edge length in the image as the weights, so BC is longer than AC.

Comment: @yowiee Can you confirm, is the graph acyclic? connected? Are you using the standard graph theory definition of 'path' (no edges or vertices repeated)?

Comment: @Dave I've updated the problem description to be explicit that the graph is acyclic and connected but not directed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that all the longest paths must begin and end on a leaf node ( one that has exactly one link )

So you can optimize your search by only looking at pairs of leaf nodes.

Comment: The OP doesn't say this is a tree, so I don't think this claim is right. E.g., if edges from a cycle are part of the longest path and that cycle only has one vertex that connects to the rest of the graph then at least one end of the path won't be a leaf. Similarly, both ends of the path could be in such cycles so neither has to be a leaf.

Comment: @Dave You can always get a LONGER path by going round the cycle one more time.  So, for the question to ne meaningful, the graph must be acyclic.

Comment: Not if the OP is using language carefully. A walk can have repeated edges & vertices, a trail can have repeated vertices but not edges, and a path can have neither.

Comment: @revenspoint this is a helpful suggestion.  The algorithm I'm developing creates a path starting at each leaf node.  Steps to the adjoining vertex and prunes the leaf.  At each new leaf node, delete all but the longest path that ends at the vertex.  Continue until there is <=2 vertices left in the graph.  This will leave 2 paths remaining which can be joined to create the final path.

Comment: Glad my answer was useful - you can upvote to indicate so.  Not sure you need to prune your graph - just record the longest path found and update the record when you find a longer one.

Answer (score 0):

An acyclic connected graph is called a tree in graph theory.

To find the longest path in an undirected edge-weighted tree:

1. Pick any vertex,  `u`
2. Find the longest path from `u` -- say it ends at `v`
3. Find the longest path from `v` -- say it ends at `w`

The path you found from v to w is the longest path in your tree. For steps 2 & 3, I don't think there's any reason to prefer BFS vs DFS.

Running time: BFS & DFS are O(|V| + |E|), but since this is a tree we know there is one fewer edge than vertex, so our total run time drops to O(|V|).